# Curious user presses key when application is in background process, how to ignore this type of additional key strokes

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, user-interface, sendkeys

I am working in C# win form application 4.0, where on a form, I am using 3 text boxes, on each text-box, when user enters 'Tab' key then focus jump to next text box.

now on first text-box on validating event I have added some code to check data validity, it connects to database server and takes time of some nano seconds, meanwhile user presses more 'Tab' keys, so that's why my focus shifts on 3rd or 4th text box, it didn't jump on second text box.

Please guide me how resolve this problem. how to ignore this key strokes.

I need a solution where user interface will be suspended until validating event is not performed.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the database right when the application is launched?

Comment: You could either validate input asynchronously or focus your TextBox absolutely by setting the `ActiveControl`. Ignoring the users key strokes seems like a bad way to go.

Comment: You might want to show to the user that your application is busy (with a progressBar, a loading gif...). This way, he won't press `Enter` again and again.

Comment: Otiel : we can not assume end user behavior, so that we have to apply fix solution. we can not assume that end user will not do mistakes so that mistakes will not occur.

Comment: To all : i have edited my question, the problem is not of "SendKey", where as, the problem is use enter tab key when application is in background process and UI is not available to accept further key strokes.

Comment: Not sure if my edit helps you out at all, but please respond directly to my answer so we can help you further

Comment: thanx for reply and good answer, and sorry for i am not putted my problem in right way. Problem is not the send key, if user presses tab key then this problem occures as well, problem is when focus is on TextBox1 and user presses tab key then TextBox1.Validating event occures it takes time of 0.5 second, meanwhile user presses again tab key then after coming out of validating procedure, UI have two pending key commands and my cursor jumps over TextBox3, where as the second Tab Key press should be ignored or any key stroke should be ignored while validating procedure is in process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, there is no reason to send the TAB key. Simply set `Focus` on the textbox you want to have focus.

What you want to do is listen to `OnKeyDown` for the textbox or control you have focus on at the time you want the enter key to be ignored. By setting `e.Handled` to `true`, the key press will be ignored.

```
private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (bIgnoreInput)
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Edit:

I would suggest having a button press to trigger the validation instead of just when the text changes (if that is what you are doing as it is not very clear). That way you can handle the validation and provide user feedback (such as a progress bar or waiting animation).

If you don't want any input at all, set `Enabled` to `false` on the text boxes until you are done handling the code. When a control is not enabled, no events are triggered. Please be sure to also check `InvokeRequired` and `Invoke` if it is.

```
void ValidateInput()
{
    SetisValidatingState(true);

    System.Threading.Thread workThread = new System.Threading.Thread(delegate() 
        { 
            ////
            // Validate here
            ////
            SetisValidatingState(false);
        });
    workThread.Start();
}


delegate void SetisValidatingStateDelegate(bool state);
void SetisValidatingState(bool state)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new SetisValidatingStateDelegate(SetisValidatingState), new object[] { state });
        return;
    }

    textBox1.AcceptsTabs = textBox2.AcceptsTabs = textBox3.AcceptsTabs = textBox4.AcceptsTabs = !state; // Disable tab while validating = true
    progressBar.visible = state; // show progress while validating = true
}
```

Comment: thanx for reply and good answer, and sorry for i am not putted my problem in right way. Problem is not the send key, if user presses tab key then this problem occures as well, problem is when focus is on TextBox1 and user presses tab key then TextBox1.Validating event occures it takes time of 0.5 second, meanwhile user presses again tab key then after coming out of validating procedure, UI have two pending key commands and my cursor jumps over TextBox3, where as the second Tab Key press should be ignored or any key stroke should be ignored while validating procedure is in process.

Comment: Your best bet is to lock the entire window and show a progress bar

Comment: Ohh! okk, but is it good solution to show progress bar for 0.5 seconds.

Comment: Always, you never know when it might take a little extra time. You always want the user to know when something is happening when they can't do something so they don't assume the application has locked up

Comment: You can also set `AcceptsTabs` on the text box to false while validating. That should ignore them

Comment: here is one more problem, because i am working on database, when transaction to database happen, execution is not remain on main application, in this time whole application is halted, if i shows progress bar, then it will display halted progress bar, no increment will show in it.

Comment: You want to run the execution of the validation on a new thread. see my answer, where I spawn the thread to do the actual work? That will allow the UI to still function and not wait

Comment: No, our rules in application, doesn't permit me to set accept tab.

Comment: I assume this is hownwork then? At the end of validating, set Focus on the TextBox that should have focus. That way if the user tabbed, it wont matter because you will set the focus to exactly where it needs to be

Comment: Humm! threading would be a great solution, it will not halt current working of end user, although for knowledge only i want to know is there no solution that we can stop windows to accept any key stroke.

Comment: To create new thread each time of validating, is it time consuming ?

Comment: You should always do work on a background thread. Locking the main thread will always look to the user that your application is locked up.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27095/discussion-between-haider-ali-wajihi-and-jeremyk)

Answer (score 3):

Call GetNextControl before calling the validation server to find out where you should move focus when validation completes.  When validation completes, call Focus() on that control

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.getnextcontrol.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce a flag (dbFlag) of type bool which you can set befor doing your database-stuff and reset it afterwards.

Your KeyDown-Code can than look like:

```
private void KeyDown(object sender, KeyDownEventArgs e)
{
   //check the state of your flag
   if(!dbFlag && e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
      SendKeys.Send("{Tab}");
}
```